# HTTP Request returns 404 in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the simplest of architectures as follows, just for the sake of testing :

[image: Project architecture]

ctrl.java :

```
@RestController
public class ctrl {
    @GetMapping(value = "/plain-text", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getPlainText() {
        System.out.println("Hit me!");
        return ResponseEntity.ok("This is plain text to be displayed in the page.");
    }
}
```

DemoApplication.java :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Requesting http://localhost:8080/plain-text

returns a 404 error. I can't wrap my head around it.

I have all the needed dependencies : JPA, Spring Web, Spring starter web...etc

Comment: could you share the stacktrace?

Comment: stacktrace doesnt show any errors obviously. can paste it if you really want

Comment: You can [enable debug logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/features.html#features.logging) in your application and see what happens when it receives the request.

Comment: Try adding an Accept header of text/plain. I don't know if that will fix it or not. From curl -H "Accept: text/plain".

Comment: Not sure if this is the same but in tomcat access log i get :
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Nov/2023:17:56:21 +0100] "GET /plain-text HTTP/1.1" 404 700

which adds basically nothing

Comment: What is the context?  Maybe the URL needs to be: http://localhost:8080/demo/plain-text

Comment: FWIW I recreated your application with the same structure (on Linux) and couldn't reproduce your issue. Maybe you've got a firewall that's blocking port 8080?

Comment: Port 8080 is open and well, accept header didnt change anything

Comment: executing the project without tomcat works just fine, i guess its a configuration problem from my side though I cant figure out what

Comment: Were you running a separate instance of Tomcat? By default, Spring Boot includes a Tomcat instance inside your application. So if your separate Tomcat instance was already listening on port 8080, your application would have failed to also listen on that port because that was already allocated to the separate Tomcat instance.

Comment: I used a separate instance but even changing port didn't help it

Answer (score 0):

You should use @RequestMapping annotation.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class ctrl 
{
@GetMapping(value = "/plain-text", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> getPlainText() 
{
    System.out.println("Hit me!");
    return ResponseEntity.ok("This is plain text to be displayed in the page.");
}}
```